# Please explain about Func delegate in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda

In .NET 4.0, have a built-in delegate method:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

It is used in LINQ extesion methods, example:

```
IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

I don't understand clearly about Func delegate, why does the following lambda expression match it:

```
// p is a XElement object
p=>p.Element("firstname").Value.StartsWith("Q")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Func<T,TResult>` simply means: a method that accepts a `T` as a parameter, and returns a `TResult`. Your lambda matches it, in that for `T=XElement` and `TResult=bool`, your lambda takes a `T` and returns a `TResult`. In that *particular* case it would commonly be referred to as a predicate. The compiler can infer the generic type arguments (`T` and `TResult`) based on usage in many (not all) scenarios.

Note the `in` and `out` refer to the (co|contra)-variance behaviour of the method - not the *normal* usage of `out` (i.e. `out` here **doesn't** mean by-ref, not assumed to be assigned on call, and needs to be assigned before exit).

Comment: If you change the word 'method' to function in this context, I'll agree with your answer and will upvote it.

Comment: @Lajos no, it would be **incorrect** to do that; C# in particular *does not have* functions; a delegate such as `Func<T,TResult>` binds to a **method**.

Comment: Well, you can create Modules where you can add functions which are not part of any class, so, C# has functions too, not only methods. I'm almost sure (but didn't test) that a function in a module can be a predicate. I might be wrong in the second part of this comment though.

Comment: +1 You are right, this only exists in Visual Basic. I was sure C# has smoething for that, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`Func<T,TResult>` takes two generic parameters: `T` and `TResult`. As you can see, `T` is the type for the `arg` parameter and `TResult` is the return type, therefore your code

```
// p is a XElement object
p=>p.Element("firstname").Value.StartsWith("Q")
```

Will be a valid `Func<XElement, bool>`.

The [in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) generic modifiers mean that the parameters are contravariant or covariant.

Comment: And the magic trick, is that .NET uses [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) to figure out the type of `T` and `TResult`. So it automatically infer `T` from the type of `p`, and `TResult` from the `StartsWith("Q")` result value (boolean).

Comment: That exactly! Which as Marc pointed out, a delegate returning a `boolean` is commonly referred to as a predicate